# Nginx serving images very slow

Tags: nginx, web-server

I am currently deploying a simple django site using AWS and Nginx as frontend server. My sites has many images with average size of 400kb and I want to load them as quickly as possible on a slow connection. But it takes lot of time to load.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711282/nginx-slow-static-file-serving-slower-than-node) but it didn't help. I find no other way but to compress my images manually which is definitely going to reduce their quality and look bad.

***nginx.conf***

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

***myproject.conf*** (sites-enabled)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/app.sock;
    }
    location /static/ {
        gzip_static on;
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/static/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Include your site config instead of main nginx config file, this one doesn't help at all.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Edited my question check it out

Comment: Are your images located in the `static` directory?

Comment: yes its in static folder also I have css and javascript as well in there.

Comment: The post you are referring to suggest `sendfile_max_chunk` setting to be set at `512k` while your config has `512` meaning that every static file would be send by chunks of 512 bytes. If your site doesn't have a high load just remove it otherwise try something from 64k to 512k and check the results.

Comment: Additionally using `root /home/ubuntu/myproject;` instead of `alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/static/;` in the `location /static/` would be slightly better.

Comment: @IvanShatsky tried with `64k` as well as `512k` with no improvement so I removed it and I tried `root /home/ubuntu/myproject/` and still no improvement. I restart the nginx after changing the settings with `sudo services nginx restart` or do I also need to reboot the server itself ?

Comment: Restarting nginx should be sufficient. Sorry, don't know how to help further.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for your time. God bless you and give you more knowledge ;)

Comment: @Ahtisham Having same issue, did you solve this issue ?